# MS Word How to select hidden text

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I have a set of code that would select a specific range of text to be hidden and I need to have a macro that would select those hidden text and unhide them.  However, I don't know how to select those hidden text without first displaying them.  Is there a way to select hidden text while they're not displayed.  I'm trying to create a dynamic template where if certain conditions are selected only certain text will appear.  So far this is my code to unhide hidden text.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=4, Extend:=wdExtend
    With Selection.Font
        .NameFarEast = "+Body Asian"
        .NameAscii = "+Body"
        .NameOther = "+Body"
        .Name = "+Body"
        .Size = 11
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = False
        .Underline = wdUnderlineNone
        .UnderlineColor = wdColorAutomatic
        .StrikeThrough = False
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = False
        .Outline = False
        .Emboss = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Hidden = False
        .SmallCaps = False
        .AllCaps = False
        .Color = wdColorAutomatic
        .Engrave = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .Spacing = 0
        .Scaling = 100
        .Position = 0
        .Kerning = 0
        .Animation = wdAnimationNone
        .DisableCharacterSpaceGrid = False
        .EmphasisMark = wdEmphasisMarkNone
        .Ligatures = wdLigaturesNone
        .NumberSpacing = wdNumberSpacingDefault
        .NumberForm = wdNumberFormDefault
        .StylisticSet = wdStylisticSetDefault
        .ContextualAlternates = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The hidden text has to be visible on the screen to be selected. So you need this in your code:
`ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True`
However, you may be able to not let the user see them by `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of the code. Not tested though.

Comment: @masoud adding 'ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True' works! I never thought of that.  I'm not sure about 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False' though.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidden text has to be visible on the screen to be selected. So you need this in your code. You don't need to un-hide them;

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True
```

If you want the user to not see the texts while running this may do the job. However, it is not tested;

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Remember to turn it back on at the end of your code;

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```